# MongoDB: Searching for a keyword from a long string with under Array->Object->Object

Tags: string, mongodb, search, text

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Utr.png)I am trying to extract keywords from a DB with reviews about hotels. 
The document is structured in the following way (and there are 10 documents with the same structure):
(1) Document 
    (2) Object ID
    (3) Reviews (Array) - This has about 233 objects under it, so i am expanding object 0
       (4) 0 (This is the first object under Reviews)
          (4.1)- Review ID (String)
          (4.2)- Content (String) - this is where the review comments lie and i need to get to this.
I am very new queries and any kind of programming. I am unable to get to this 'Content' node. Is there anyone who can help me to get to this node and then search a text word from this string, to return this object as a result.

Comment: Please provide the sample input and expected output.

Comment: Yathish, I have added the input data image. the biggest problem in this assignment is getting to the 'Content' node under Reviews Array. 
The structure of Array -> Object under which we have the content field is hard to get to.